# Spell checker using lucene

Tags: solr, lucene, spell-checking, autocorrect

I am trying to write a spell corrector using the lucene spellchecker. I would want to give it a single text file with blog text content. The problem is that it works only when I give it one sentence/word per line in my dictionary file. Also the suggest API returns results  without giving any weightage to  number of occurences. Following is the source code

```
   public class SpellCorrector {

        SpellChecker spellChecker = null;

        public SpellCorrector() {
                try {
                        File file = new File("/home/ubuntu/spellCheckIndex");
                        Directory directory = FSDirectory.open(file);

                        spellChecker = new SpellChecker(directory);

                        StandardAnalyzer analyzer = new StandardAnalyzer(Version.LUCENE_36);
                        IndexWriterConfig config = new IndexWriterConfig(Version.LUCENE_36, analyzer);
                        spellChecker.indexDictionary(
                                        new PlainTextDictionary(new File("/home/ubuntu/main.dictionary")), config, true);
                                                                        //Should I format this file with one sentence/word per line?

                } catch (IOException e) {

                }

        }

        public String correct(String query) {
                if (spellChecker != null) {
                        try {
                                String[] suggestions = spellChecker.suggestSimilar(query, 5);  
                                 // This returns the suggestion not based on occurence but based on when it occured

                                if (suggestions != null) {
                                        if (suggestions.length != 0) {
                                                return suggestions[0];
                                        }
                                }
                        } catch (IOException e) {
                                return null;
                        }
                }
                return null;
        }
}
```

Do I need to make some changes?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Regarding your first issue, sounds like the expected, documented dictionary format, here in the [PlainTextDictionary API](http://lucene.apache.org/core/4_1_0/suggest/org/apache/lucene/search/spell/PlainTextDictionary.html).  If you want to pass arbitrary text in, you might want to index it and use a [LuceneDictionary](http://lucene.apache.org/core/4_1_0/suggest/org/apache/lucene/search/spell/LuceneDictionary.html) instead, or possibly a [HighFrequencyDictionary](http://lucene.apache.org/core/4_1_0/suggest/org/apache/lucene/search/spell/HighFrequencyDictionary.html), depending on your needs.

The Spellchecker suggests replacements based on the similarity between the words (based on [Levenstein Distance](http://lucene.apache.org/core/4_1_0/suggest/org/apache/lucene/search/spell/LevensteinDistance.html)), before any other concern.  If you want it to only recommend more popular terms as suggestions, you should pass a [SuggestMode](http://lucene.apache.org/core/4_1_0/suggest/org/apache/lucene/search/spell/SuggestMode.html) to [SpellChecker.suggestSimilar](http://lucene.apache.org/core/4_1_0/suggest/org/apache/lucene/search/spell/SpellChecker.html#suggestSimilar%28java.lang.String,%20int,%20org.apache.lucene.index.IndexReader,%20java.lang.String,%20org.apache.lucene.search.spell.SuggestMode%29).  This ensures that matches suggested are at least as strong, popularity-wise, as the word they are intended to replace.

If you must override how Lucene decides on best matches, you can do that with [SpellChecker.setComparator](http://lucene.apache.org/core/4_1_0/suggest/org/apache/lucene/search/spell/SpellChecker.html#setComparator%28java.util.Comparator%29), creating your own Comparator on [SuggestWord](http://lucene.apache.org/core/4_1_0/suggest/org/apache/lucene/search/spell/SuggestWord.html)s.  Since SuggestWord exposes `freq` to you, it should be easy to arrange found matches by popularity.